# Ordering with filter in Google app engine data store

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In `Google DataStore`, I used ordering by one property and filtered by other property. But Datastore throws exception.

Lets say i filter property of firstname and ordered by creationdate

```
String firstname = "Smith";
query.setFilter("firstname == :1");
query.setOrdering("creationdate desc");
query.execute(firstname)
```

It is not working.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: The Java exceptions (I'm assuming you're using Java here) usually describes the composite index you need to add to your datastore-indexes.xml to have the query properly executed. Please check your logs or your console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I got an exception when we were dealing with multiple attributes; I was suggested to use indexing. See if that helps

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig

Comment: I got following error

    `The first sort property must be the same as the property to which the inequality filter is applied.  In your query the first sort property is creationdate but the inequality filter is on firstname.`